# Which item to administer to improve the standard error of the item difficulty estimate the most?

Tags: logistic, experiment-design, item-response-theory, active-learning

I have a student with a known ability level and a set of items with an estimated difficulty. The probability of a student getting an item correct follows an 1 parameter logistic model (also known as 1PL or Rasch model) p(y=1) = logistic(item_difficulty - student_ability), which can be modeled, and parameters estimated using random-effects logistic regression.

I have estimated item difficulties, and I would like to administer an item to a student with the known ability so that the standard error of the estimated item difficulty would improve the most after learning the response of the student. I found out that the most informative item should be one where the estimated item difficulty equals the subject ability, i.e., where the probability of getting the item correct equals 50%. However, this does not take into account different standard errors of difficulty estimates. So maybe I would rather administer an item that is further from 50%, but I am more uncertain about its difficulty.

So my goal is an optimal item assignment to subjects to maximize the precision of item difficulty estimates.

Comment: This sounds like an adaptive design optimization problem. Maybe have a look at this paper:  https://link.springer.com/article/10.3758/s13428-020-01386-4